# Apache web server accessible within LAN, but not from WAN

Tags: apache, centos7, iptables

I'm trying to host a website on my home server, mostly for practice and private usage. I can access the website within LAN network of the router, but not from WAN. I opened port 80 and 443, but cannot connect to it from outside of LAN. I forwarded the ports on my router as well and I tried stopping iptables and then connecting to website, but no luck. I don't know what to do anymore... Please help

**iptables -vnL**

```
[root@offworld teamspeak]# iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       84.255.210.79        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       84.255.210.79        0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       84.255.210.79        0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       84.255.210.79        0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       84.255.209.79        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       84.255.209.79        0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       84.255.209.79        0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:53
   12  1614 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       84.255.209.79        0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53
 2844  554K LOCALINPUT  all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    3   180 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   31  1548 INVALID    tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    2    80 ACCEPT     all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:20
    1    44 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:21
    1    44 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:2008
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:10011
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:30033
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW tcp dpt:41144
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:20
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW udp dpt:9987
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 limit: avg 1/sec burst 5
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0 limit: avg 1/sec burst 5
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
   49  2084 LOGDROPIN  all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.example
    ServerName domain.example
    ServerAlias www.domain.example
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.example/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/domain.example/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/domain.example/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**netstat -ant**

```
[root@offworld teamspeak]# netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30033           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10011           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0    256 192.168.1.4:22          192.168.1.2:50066       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.4:22          192.168.1.2:51516       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.4:22          192.168.1.2:50058       ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::30033                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::10011                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::201                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: What are you using to test from the outside? Do you have a port scanner on a device outside your lan? I suspect you are not set up properly to enable access through your router from the wan

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone thanks for the response. I'm using mobile data to connect to my website... I also tried http://canyouseeme.org/... Thing is, my ftp, ssh and ts3 are working just fine, but port 80 doesn't seem to come through router or something is blocking it on the server (which is more likely), but I have no clue to what it could be

Comment: Also when I turn off iptables firewall, I can use my domain name, but I get redirected to the local ip address when using on LAN

Comment: Ok I find some of what you're saying ambiguous.

Try the following and let me know what you see

1. find out your external address and scan it using a port scanner. Is the port you need to use open?

2.If not, sort that out on your router - if yes then try and telnet to that port from the outside. Do you get any response? Do you see evidence of connection to your web server?

Comment: The port is closed to the public, but I can access other ports like for ex. Teamspeak 3 server, SSH, FTP, etc... They all required port forwarding on the router and opening the port on the server... [Here](https://imgur.com/a/hqXyc) you can see the port 80 should be open on the router.

Comment: If the port is still close but configured to be open then the problem is with the router.

Comment: I've somehow managed to get the port open, but I still can't connect to my website, port is forwarded on router, open in the server firewall and set in the apache files...

Comment: Well in short, I've tried everything, to rule out the fact that my router wasn't the problem, I connected my pc directly to modem and the port was then still closed. When I rebooted pc, the old iptables save somehow overwritten the new one and the port was suddenly open. No clue what was blocking it.